# How to pass bash variable to into file

Tags: python, linux, bash, automation

I want to create host_install.py from bash variables.
So I have tried following :

```
#!/bin/bash

CM_HOST="10.0.5.99"
CM_USER="admin"
CM_PASSWORD="admin"
CM_CLUSTER_NAME="cluster"
INSTANCE_TYPE=`wget -q -O- http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-type`

cat > /tmp/host_install.py <<EOF
import socket
import commands
from time import sleep

cluster_name = "$CM_CLUSTER_NAME"
role_template = "$INSTANCE_TYPE"

print cluster_name
print role_template

EOF

chmod a+x /tmp/host_install.py
/tmp/host_install.py
```

This is printing

```
$CM_CLUSTER_NAME
$INSTANCE_TYPE
```

instead of

```
cluster
c3.2xlarge
```

What wrong I am doing here ?

Comment: As shown, it works fine for me.  The error that you show is what would have happened if you had quoted EOF as in `cat > /tmp/host_install.py <<"EOF"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables are accessed through [os.environ](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#process-parameters)

```
import os
cluster_name =  os.environ['CM_CLUSTER_NAME']
role_template =  os.environ['INSTANCE_TYPE']
```

[Python default installation](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#how-installation-works) on Windows is `C:\Python`. If you want to find out while running python you can do:

```
import sys
print sys.prefix
```